# Is there a minimum stock price for tsx listings?

Tags: stocks, investing, canada, toronto-stock-exchange

For example, NYSE stocks must maintain $1 a share. I have searched and can only find data on tsx-v.

Answer (score 5):

A quick Google for Toronto Stock Exchange regulations  provided "Part VII Halting of Trading, Suspension and Delisting of Securities."  There are many reasons listed for delisting but in regard to  price, the following section addresses it:

3) Market Value and Public Distribution

Sec. 711.

TSX will normally consider the delisting of securities of a listed issuer if, in the opinion of TSX, it appears that the public distribution, price, or trading activity of the securities has been so reduced as to make further dealings in the securities on TSX unwarranted.

Sec. 712.

Specifically, participating securities may be delisted if:

(a) the market value of the listed issuer's issued securities that are listed on TSX is less than $3,000,000 over any period of 30 consecutive trading days; or

(b) the market value of the listed issuer's freely-tradable, publicly held securities is less than $2,000,000 over any period of 30 consecutive trading days; or

(c) the number of freely-tradable, publicly held securities is less than 500,000; or

(d) the number of public security holders, each holding a board lot or more, is less than 150.

Non-participating securities will be subject to (b) above as well as Section 711.

http://tmx.complinet.com/en/display/display_viewall.html?rbid=2072&element_id=327&record_id=327&filtered_tag&print=1